# parsing json from asp.net mvc controller action to ajax.actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I am working on asp.net mvc application and I have added an actionlink like this:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Event Notifications", "processCallrecording", new { Id = ViewData["RecordingIDsEdit"] }, new AjaxOptions
{
    OnSuccess = "StatusChanged",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
})%>
```

My controller is like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ProcessCallRecording(int Id = 0)
        {
int result = id;
 return Json(new {NewStatus = result.ToString()});
        }
```

My js function is like this:

```
function StatusChanged(data) {   
alert("order #:" + data.NewStatus + "has a new status: "
    + data.NewStatus);
}
```

and I see undefined in alert. I am struggling for last 2 hours on this issue. Please suggest me what is wrong ?

Comment: use firebug or IE Developer tools to see what data is coming from the ajax call ? Is it a valid JSON ?

Comment: response returned is: {"NewStatus":"2.88000000000001"}

Comment: You have logged "data" variable?

Comment: what does it mean by logged ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Event Notifications", "processCallrecording", new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["RecordingIDsEdit"]) }, new AjaxOptions
{
    OnSuccess = "StatusChanged",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
})%>
```

as you i have used viewData so you are missing Convert it into Int. also make sure i have added these script before action link.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```